# Один цикл VS несколько - производительность

Tags: циклы, производительность

Долгое время возвращаюсь к одному глупому вопросу, неопределенность в котором не дает мне спокойно работать, пришло время узнать ответ.

Допустим есть модель(все псевдокод):

```
class MyClass{
   a;
   b;
}
```

И рассмотрим две ситуации:

```
for(...){
  myClass.a;
  myClass.b;
}
```

и

```
for(...){
  myClass.a;
}

for(...){
  myClass.b;
}
```

То есть в цикле нужно сделать обращение к полям/методам a,b.
Если "раскрыть скобки", то получим:
Первый случай:

```
 myClass.a;
 myClass.b;
 myClass.a;
 myClass.b;
```

Второй:

```
 myClass.a;
 myClass.a;
...
 myClass.b
 myClass.b;
```

То есть одно и тоже по сути, не считая работы циклов.

В данном контексте выглядит как бред, но часто бывает что для удобства и читаемости лучше разбить обращения на насколько циклов, и даже поместить их в разные части кода, а читать циклы на километр или с множество непонятных поворотов- никто не любит.

**Вопрос**: есть  ли существенное проигрывание в производительности второго случая перед первым? Или проще говоря: стоит ли парится, или величины ничтожно малы? (нужно помнить что: "количество итераций в цикле, количество параметров к которым нужно обратится и сложность их выполнения - могут быть абсолютно любыми)

Языки: любые, но если это важно,то больше интересуют c#, java, kotlin.

PS: Да, я находил подобные вопросы, но такого, что бы убедится в правильности -  нет.

Спасибо!

**UPDATE**

Я написал простой код, по типу того что в примере, и протестировал на разных компиляторах.

Результат:
До 1000+ итераций: 2 цикла, 4 цикла вместо оного не проиграли в производительности, что удивительно работали даже быстрей.

От 10к - потери начинают возрастать и видимо чем больше итераций тем больше потерь.

Все еще жду универсальное решение.

Comment: почему бы просто не померить сколько времени выполняется один вариант, сколько второй?

Comment: @Grundy, в процессе, но хочется узнать в широком смысле.

Comment: в широком смысле: может зависеть от входных данных и результатов работы компилятора

Comment: Мне кажется все зависит от того, что записано в условиях цикла. Т е если вы в своих примерах ходите по всему списку ваших объектов (например их 10) то в первом случае вы один раз их обходитесь, а второй случай 2 раза (при чем одни и те же)

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, да, но если посмотреть раздел "раскрыть скобки", то можно понять что не в проходах дело, а в обращениях, отчасти в этом и вопрос.

Comment: Ходить 1 раз по миллиону записей или 2...вот в чем вопрос. Я вот не пойму...вас интересует эффективность? Или вам это все равно, и вам интересно только "удобство" между подходами

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц эффективность в обычном случае, но если она настолько мала, что ей можно пренебречь, то удобство.

Comment: если рассматривается удобство, то все зависит от того, что вы хотите впихнуть помимо того кода, что вы написали